# Question about IF ELSE and mathematic in python

Tags: python, pandas

Data
Time,PM2.5,
1/1/2014,9
2/1/2014,10

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('xx.csv')
data = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

```
def calculation(y):
    if 0 < y and y < 12:
        bello=data.assign(API=(50/12)*y)
    elif 12.1 <= y and y <= 50.4:
        bello=data.assign(API=(((100-51)/(50.4-12.1))*(y-12.1))+51)
    elif 50.5 <= y and y <= 55.4:
        bello=data.assign(API=(((150-101)/(55.4-50.5))*(y-50.5))+101)
    elif 55.5 <= y and y <= 150.4:
        bello=data.assign(API=(((200-151)/(150.4-55.5))*(y-55.5))+151)
    elif 150.5 <= y and y <= 250.4:
        bello=data.assign(API=(((300-201)/(250.4-150.5))*(y-150.5))+201)
    elif 250.5 <= y and y <= 350.4:
        bello=data.assign(API=(((400-301)/(350.4-250.5))*(y-250.5))+301)
    else:
        bello=data.assign(API=(((500-401)/(500.4-350.5))*(y-350.5))+401)
    return bello

y=data['PM2.5']
print(calculation(y))
```

Hi everyone,

I want to convert air quality data to PM2.5 with above condition and equation using coding above.

I received an error "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().".

I hope someone can tell me what is the problem.

Thanks in advance.

I wrote the coding above but show error. Hope someone can tell what is the problem of my coding.

Comment: `y` is an entire column of data. When is an entire column between, for example, 0 and 12? When *one* value is? When *all* of them are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you can rewrite the function for single value and use df.apply(...)

```
import pandas as pd
data  = pd.DataFrame({'PM2.5': [15, 50, 1000]})

def calculation(y):
    if 0<y<12:
        return (50/12)*y
    elif 12.1 <= y  <= 50.4:
        return (((100-51)/(50.4-12.1))*(y-12.1))+51
    ## .... 
    else:
        return (((500-401)/(500.4-350.5))*(y-350.5))+401

y=data['PM2.5']
print(y.apply(calculation))
```

This is close to your code, however faster solutions might exists by vectorizing.